# url path [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#img").load("loader.php .allcon,",function(){
    $(".allcon").attr();
    });
});
```

so HTML code output:

```
<div class="1">
 <div class="2">
   <a href="/xxxx/xxxx.html">
 </div>
</div>
```

URL target output: "localhost/xxxx/xxxx.html"

There will be a way to make URL: http://website.com/xxxx/xxxx.html

Comment: Have you tried to modify your HTML code?

Comment: Can't Modify, I Use file_get_content..

Comment: Maybe associated with .htaccess?

Comment: In that case you can modify all `a`'s with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

More about [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

```
$('a').each(function(i) {
    var _o = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', 'http://website.com/' + _o;
});
```